# Why is the domain name missing from the logout redirect?

Tags: migration, apache, mod-rewrite, xampp

My development computer recently had to be rebuilt so I am now trying to migrate a WordPress site from the hosting company to my development PC.  So far I have done this:

1. Installed XAMPP.
2. Download the PHP files using FTP and put them in `htdocs\mysite`
3. Create a virtual host called: `localhost.MySite`.
4. Export the .sql from the host using PHPMyAdmin
5. Open the .sql and to a find and replace replacing: `www.mysite.co.uk` with: `localhost.MySite`
6. Use PHPMyAdmin on my local PC to load the .sql
7. Make changes to wp_config.php:

   ```
   define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/mysite');
   define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/mysite');
   ```

Everything appeared to work e.g. the multi sites; the admin panel etc.  The only issue I have is when I logout of the admin panel; I am redirected to: `http://wp-login.php/?loggedout=true` instead of:  `http://localhost.MySite/wp-login.php/?loggedout=true`.  What can I do?

I have spent a while Googling this e.g. I have looked here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/logout-redirect-not-working-3/page/2/

This issue does not happen on the live website.

**Update**

I only appear to have theis issue on the root site of the multi site.

Answer (score 0):

I have traced the problem to this code in wp-login.php:

```
case 'logout' :
    check_admin_referer('log-out');

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    wp_logout();

    echo "hello";
    echo $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];

    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
        $redirect_to = $requested_redirect_to = $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
    } else {
        $redirect_to = 'wp-login.php?loggedout=true';
        $requested_redirect_to = '';
    }
```

It appears if I change this line:

```
$redirect_to = 'wp-login.php?loggedout=true';
```

to this:

```
$redirect_to = 'http://wp-login.php?loggedout=true';
```

Then it works as expected.  Not sure why.  In fact I can also change it to any of the following and it still works as expected:

$redirect_to = 'http://';

or

$redirect_to = 'http://somerandomsite';

Not sure what is going on.

Comment: "to this: `$redirect_to = 'http://wp-login.php?loggedout=true';`" - To clarify, you are actually changing it to the _undesirable_ URL you were being redirected to (as stated in the question)? And this "works"?!

Comment: @MrWhite, thanks.  So what do I change it to?

Comment: Well, I don't really think that code should be "changed". WordPress will likely overwrite your efforts in a later update? (I'm sure there must be something else that can be "fixed"?) What version of WP are you using? In "later"(?) versions, the URL is not hardcoded here and is instead populated with a call to `wp_login_url()`. There are several sanitization/validation checks performed after this point in the code, so setting `$redirect_to` to something invalid (which appears to be what you are doing here) is probably just resulting in the value _defaulting_ to "something else"?